# Creating a relation between events in tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, bind

I have a Listbox and a Combobox (using python's tkinter) with event functions and can't find a way to make any relation between these two events.

I built a database with sqlite3 which stores expenses (relevant columns are 'category' ,'cost').

In my GUI i have a Listbox which contains all of the database rows . 
I added a Combobox that enables me to select a specific category and after i click on one of the categories i can see only the entries with this specific category in the Listbox (simple bind and event function).

In addition to that, i have an entry widget.
Uppon clicking on a specific row in the Listbox, the cost column of that row is inserted into the entry widget.

The problem arises when i first trigger the Combobox event and then try to click on a specific row in the Listbox to triger the Listbox event. Nothing is inserted into the entry widget.

My code for these event functions:

```
global selected_cat
"""event triggered by clicking on a row in Combobox.
   lb is Listbox widget.
   selected_cat will store the selected category.
   db is the Database
"""
def get_selected_category(event):
    selected_cat=cat.get()
    lb.delete(0,END)
    for i in db.search_by_category(selected_cat):
        lb.insert(END,i)

"""event triggered by clicking on a row in Listbox.
   lb is Listbox widget.
   selected_tuple is a tuple which contains (id,category,cost)
"""
def get_selected_row(event):

        global selected_tuple
        print(lb.curselection())
        index=lb.curselection()[0]
        if index != ():
            selected_tuple=lb.get(index)
            print(selected_tuple)
            e1.delete(0,END)
            e1.insert(END,str(selected_tuple[2])+" ILS")
```

these are the bindings :

```
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',get_selected_row)
cat.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_selected_category)
```

Comment: Looks  ok, there must be a error in the `try: ... except:...` block, it's bad practice to block **all**. Remove it and show the Traceback and the output of `print(lb.curselection())` and `print(selected_tuple)`.

Comment: Code adjusted. 
Now i don't get an error but i still have a problem with displaying the column in the entry .  
"The problem arises when i first trigger the Combobox event and then try to click on a specific row in the Listbox to triger the Listbox event. Nothing is inserted into the entry widget."

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to retrace the problem. 
The problem was caused by my Database class which has a view function that returns 4 elements inside a tuple but some other view functions i had returned only 3. 
So the indexing of " selected_tuple[2] " was an empty string and that's why i couldn't see any representation of that value in the entry.

Thank you for the help and guidance !